# How to make a border in square box using css

Tags: html, css

How to make border radius like the below using css

[image]

Comment: Please first show your attempt to this. Share your code that you tried!

Comment: can i see what you tried with

Comment: Thanks @caramba, i got the solution, sorry for the repeated question

Comment: See bottom part of this -> http://css-shapes.xyz/border-styles